# Edit an online template using HTML

Tags: html, templates, edit

I have an Online HTML Form,there is a drop down menu includes user to select scheduled and reminder.Finally it produces an PDF template.The HTML code for that part is
  `<tbody>
          {% for task in job.tasks %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- Dates can be formatted with Ruby date syntax -->
                {{ task.scheduled_at  | date: "%m/%d/%y %l:%M %p" }} -
                {{ task.ends_at  | date: "%m/%d/%y %l:%M %p" }}
              </td>
              <td>{{ task.name }}</td>
              **<td>{{ task.task_type.name}}</td>**

              **<td>{{task.task_employee.name}}</td>**
            </tr>

          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>`
I want only to display only when user select task type scheduled.How can i modify that *** section to have a output like that.